# Copy a binary tree in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary-tree

I am trying to copy a binary tree in a c++ vector and i am having a kind of error that I cant find where it is generated. This i in the header file (.h)

```
struct NyjePeme
{
  int Key;
  NyjePeme *left = NULL;
  NyjePeme *right = NULL;
};
class PemeKerkimi
{
  private:
  NyjePeme *root;

public:
  PemeKerkimi();
  ~PemeKerkimi();
```

And there are the methods i have used in .cpp file:

```
void ASCVektor(vector<int> v)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++)
    {
        if (v[i] > v[j])
        {
            int tmp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
   }
}

void printVektor(vector<int> v)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << v[i] << ", ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void copyTreeinVector(NyjePeme *T, vector<int> v)
{

  if (T != NULL)
  {
    copyTreeinVector(T->left, v);
    v.push_back(T->Key);
    copyTreeinVector(T->right, v);
    return;
  }
  return;
}

NyjePeme *PemeKerkimi::TheKSmallestElement(int k)
{
   vector<int> v;
   coptyTreeinVector(root, v);
   ASCVektor(v);
...
```

The problem is in copyTreeinVector() function and the error message is this:

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) and it takes a while to throw that message. I searched about that error and it is generated due to bad use of pointers... but I cant find the problem in my code

Comment: PemeKerkimi = BinaryTree
NyjePeme = Node

Just forgot to translate :)

Comment: Please present this as a [mre].  It is not possible to answer your question as posted.

Comment: You're passing your vector to your functions by value. That means whatever vector in main you're trying to copy your data into is not the same vector that exists in your function. Pass by reference instead. `std::vector<int>& v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass vector in `copyTreeinVector` function by-reference.

Instead of writing

```
void copyTreeinVector(NyjePeme *T, vector<int> v)
```

You should have written

```
void copyTreeinVector(NyjePeme *T, vector<int>& v)
```

Here are some additional links related to the issue.

[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference

Comment: @KlodjanMata Note that C++ is a value-based language, not a reference based language.  If you are familiar with languages that automatically pass objects by reference (java, C#, etc.), then that may be the reason why you made the error for C++.